# "Collection was modified error", but only on Key press and not Button click with same method call

Tags: c#

It seems like the "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error has popped up a lot here, but none of them seem to solve the issue I'm having. The odd problem I'm having is that the exception only presents itself when I press a Key which is bound to a command, and not when I click a button tied to the same command.

XAML:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F4" Command="{Binding UpdateItemsA}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding UpdateItemsB}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="Update A" Command="{Binding UpdateItemsA}" />
    <Button Content="Update B" Command="{Binding UpdateItemsB}" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

And here's the code-behind of an ItemStuff class:

```
bool canExecute;
ICommand updateItemsA, updateItemsB;
List<string> _itemsList;
List<string> ItemsA;
List<string> ItemsB;

public ItemStuff() 
{
    canExecute = true;
    ItemsA = new List<string> { "item A", "item B", "item C" };
    ItemsB = new List<string> { "item D", "item E", "item F" };
    ItemsList = ItemsA;
}

public ICommand UpdateItemsA
{
    get
    {
        return updateItemsA
                ?? (updateItemsA = new CommandHandler(() => UpdateMainItemsA(), canExecute));
    }
}

public ICommand UpdateItemsB
{
    get
    {
        return updateItemsB
                ?? (updateItemsB = new CommandHandler(() => UpdateMainItemsB(), canExecute));
    }
}

void UpdateMainItemsA()
{
    ItemsList = ItemsA;
}

void UpdateMainItemsB()
{
    ItemsList = ItemsB;
}

public List<string> ItemsList
{
    get
    {
        return _itemsList;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemsList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private Action _action;
    private bool _canExecute;

    public CommandHandler(Action action, bool canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

I've identified the following three areas in the XAML where if I remove them, the exception doesn't occur.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel> 

<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />

<Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

So I think the problem might have something to do with the listbox having keyboard focus and then pressing a key to switch items, because like I mentioned when you click the button to switch items there is no problem. Keyboard focus is a requirement for the app which the user should be able to navigate without ever using the mouse.

Comment: what is this structure `ImageDatabase[CurrentSelection].ImagePaths` ps nothing seems wrong with the code, however its the code we cant see that will likely cause this in your situation

Comment: Check any code that iterates `MainImages`. Maybe one of those is modifying it?

Comment: @TheGeneral ImageDatabase is an list of objects I created. The individual object represents a photo album which has several properties, one of those being ImagePaths which is a list of strings where the images are located. CurrentSelection represents the currently viewed photo album. User has the option to change to different albums throughout the list. Sorry if I didn't put enough code up. I was trying to simplify it to maybe help make it easier to solve.

Comment: @mjwills I thought that's what I was doing by showing the Button and the Key both pointing to the exact same command. Button works when I press it, Key doesn't. Very strange. I'll try to expand the code a bit more.

Comment: @mjwills I have updated my original post and code to try to better show the issue. Someone can now take this code and paste it into a new solution to see the problem first hand. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a part in your code which we can't see here obviously and you are doing some work with that "ImageDatabase[CurrentSelection].ImagePaths" while the code is in foreach loop.. you can use .ToList() in foreach line OR you can copy your ImagePaths to a temporary variable and start your foreach loop with that temp variable.. But these are not the correct things you should do, find where do you modify this list while the program is in foreach loop

Comment: I'll look into it, but I'm pretty sure it's not being modified. Otherwise, how come it works fine when I click the Button that uses the exact same command? The Button and Key literally point to the exact same code.

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't see all of your code but it might be because of this: when you use button your code might not be inside foreach loop but when you use key(s) your code might still doing some work inside loop

Comment: I have updated my original post with brand new code to show the issue. This code is the whole program which I have simplified to only the parts needed to reproduce the problem.